# SIMD-инструкции загрузка в регистры

Tags: c++, c, simd

Пытаюсь понять, хотя бы на самом примитивном уровне, как работать с SIMD.
Нашел вот такую статью: https://woboq.com/blog/utf-8-processing-using-simd.html

Там простой код и пояснение, но я не могу понять:

```
int fromUtf8(const char *src, int len, unsigned short *dst) 
{

//Мы будем обрабатывать ввод по 16 байт за раз, поэтому длина должна быть не менее 16.

    while(len >= 16) 
    {
 
    //Загрузить 128 бит в векторный регистр. Мы используем встроенный 'loadu', где «u» означает не выровненный. Загрузка выровненных данных намного быстрее, но здесь мы не знаем, выровнен ли источник.

        __m128i chunk = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src));
 

//Определить, является ли это ASCII, проверив, установлен ли старший бит одного байта:

        if (!_mm_movemask_epi8(chunk)) 
        {
              //....
        }

}
```

В этом коде я не могу понять - авто статьи пишет, что функция fromUtf8 принимает указатель на char* в котором находится 16 бит или 2 байта.

Но теперь авто статьи использует SIMD-функцию _mm_loadu_si128, которая загружает в регистры 128 бит или 16 байтов - по указанному источнику src, но ведь длинна src всего 2 байта.

Разве так можно делать ? Разве _mm_loadu_si128 не загрузит в регистры мусор, который будет после 2 байта в источнике src ?

Comment: `Our function takes a pointer src to the UTF-8 buffer of length len` ... `while(len >= 16)`

Comment: >>>Чё ты сказал?

Comment: @wololo, я ИДИОТ. Там же написано 16 байт, какого черта я прочитал 16 БИТ. !!

Comment: Длина `src` не два байта, а `len` байт. Интересующий вас участок по работе с 128-битными регистрами начинается с проверки, что `len` по крайней мере 16 байт. Приведите цитату, где «авто статьи пишет, что функция `fromUtf8` принимает указатель на `char*` в котором находится 16 бит или 2 байта».

Comment: По 16 бит / 2 байта будет содержать каждый элемент выходного массива `dst` - UTF16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не читал статью, но тут предельно ясно:

- Есть указатель на массив символов (источник), и в нем вовсе не 16
  бит.
- Дальше имя   `__m128i chunk` сразу подсказывает намерение встроенного
  `loadu`: обрабатывает по кускам символьную строку по 128 бит( по 16
  символов UTF-8), потому передается `reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src)`.
- И, чтобы это было в пределах источника, выполняется в цикле
  `while(len >= 16)`, и потому _mm_loadu_si128 не загрузит в регистры
  мусор.
- Но, с чего вы взяли, что длина `src` всего  байта, я не  знаю...